# chaining promise where 2nd promise is dependent on the result of the first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, promise

I am having a lot of trouble chaining two promises together in my react native app. The first promise successfully gets a value in Async storage and sets it to the state. The second promise gets the data I have from Firebase, but is dependent on the state that I set from the first promise. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import firebase from "../../firebase/fbConfig";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

let DB = firebase.firestore();

function Questions(props) {
    const [productId, setProductId] = useState("");
    const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
    const [reward, setReward] = useState("");

    const getAsyncData = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("key").then((value) => setProductId(value))
        // works fine //
    };

    const getDataFromFirebase = (productId) => {
        DB.collection("ads")
            .where("productId", "==", productId)
            .get()
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    setQuestion(doc.data().question);
                    setReward(doc.data().reward);
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
            // works fine //
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getAsyncData().then((productId) => getDataFromFirebase(productId));
        // does not work //
    });

    return (
        <>
            <View style={styles.container}>

            </View>
        </>
    );
}

export default Questions;
```

[image]

Comment: Your issue is that `getAsyncData` isn't RETURNING anything ... try `const getAsyncData = () => { return  AsyncStorage.getItem("key").then((value) => setProductId(value)); };` or `const getAsyncData = () => AsyncStorage.getItem("key").then((value) => setProductId(value));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
useEffect(() => {
  getAsyncData();
}, []);

const getAsyncData = async () => {
  try {
    const productId = await AsyncStorage.getItem("key");
    getDataFromFirebase(productId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: This worked for me! I also had a type error, but finally got it to work